# Can my ex-wife, who is Chinese, apply for a Chinese passport for our child who is an american citizen, without my consent?

Tags: passports, china

My ex wife is a Chinese citizen and I'm concerned she is attempting to take our child back to China without my consent.  I have a restraining order stating she cannot take our child out of the state he resides in, but I'm worried she will apply for a chinese passport for our child without my consent.  My child and I are American citizens.  Can my wife really apply for a Chinese passport without my permission for our child and then take him back to China?  Is there anything I can do to stop her?

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Did your wife hold permanent residence or green card at the time of the birth of the child? If she was a permanent resident, your child is not eligible for Chinese citizenship and cannot obtain a travel document anyway.

Comment: @xngtng Assuming she tells the truth to the Chinese authorities (or they actually care)

Comment: @PeterM they care *very much* about it to avoid and reduce the number of dual citizens, which is not recognized by Chinese law. You must provide the status documents of both parents at the time of the child's birth before applying for a Chinese travel document.

Comment: @xngtngThat sounds likes the start of a good answer - especially if you quote any Chinese law.

Comment: @xngtng That sounds like a pretty strong barrier to the ex-wife applying for a passport without the OP’s consent, unless ‘status documents’ are easily obtained

Comment: @Traveller I'd be more worried about the consulate accepting a claim that there are no status documents, perhaps because the mother is in the US illegally, or simply overlooking the requirement (which xngtng's answer suggests is not uncommon).

Comment: @Traveller: In a case where one parent is proven to be a Chinese citizen without foreign permanent residency, the only way the other parent's status can prevent the child from having Chinese nationality is if the other parent is a Chinese citizen with foreign permanent residency. Proving that the other parent is a non-Chinese citizen is sufficient to eliminate that possibility. I am not sure if a copy of the OP's passport or birth certificate would be sufficient, or if they would still need original documents.

Answer (score 8):

First, you can determine whether your child indeed has Chinese nationality (and be eligible for Chinese travel documents). Assuming you are not a Chinese citizen (if you are, the same analysis applies to either of the child's parents), a child born outside China gains Chinese nationality from their Chinese parent(s) if and only if no Chinese parent is settled abroad (unless the child does not gain a foreign nationality at birth).

If you wife held a green card at the time of your child's birth, the child does not have Chinese citizenship.

According to the Chinese [Nationality Law](http://www.china.org.cn/english/LivinginChina/184710.htm):

> Article 5
>
> Any person born abroad whose parents are both Chinese nationals and one of whose parents is a Chinese
> national shall have Chinese nationality. **But a person whose parents are both Chinese nationals and have both
> settled abroad, or one of whose parents is a Chinese national and has settled abroad, and who has acquired
> foreign nationality at birth *shall not* have Chinese nationality.**

Chinese law also does not recognize dual nationality:

> Article 3
>
> The People's Republic of China does not recognize dual nationality for Any Chinese national.

Although in practice, they recognize the situation of so-called "nationality conflict" whereas a person (in most case a child) is a national of China and another country at the same time according to the laws of respective countries. For example, a child born to two Chinese students in the U.S. (who are not settled, or permanent resident, in the U.S. and do not have diplomatic status) is a Chinese citizen according to Chinese law, and an American citizen under American law. The same applies to the child born to an American parent and a Chinese parent without permanent resident status in another country.

In such cases, a Chinese passport is in principle not issued. But a [Chinese travel document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Travel_Document) (旅行证) is available until the child turns 18 (even though the law does not have explicit provisions on this, but in practice, the person must "choose" the nationality they wish to keep).

To apply for the travel document for a minor, both parents' consent, in addition to their status documents at the minor's birth, is required. However, depending on the consulate, the following documents that may pose a barrier to your ex-wife's possible attempt, **may or may not** be required

- the original passports and status documents of both parents; but some consulates accept photocopies
- signed consent or delegation forms; but  only some consulates require notarization
- marriage certificate, court orders related to custody, etc.; only some consulates need this

**Note that renewal of Chinese passport or travel documents often only requires the consent and presence of one parent.**

For example, the Chinese Embassy in the U.S. (which has jurisdiction over many but not all U.S. states; China has consulates in Los Angeles, San Francisco, New York and Chicago that are responsible for neighbouring states or regions) [requires](http://us.china-embassy.gov.cn/chn/lsfw/zj/hzlxz/202204/t20220416_10668741.htm#%E6%97%85%E8%A1%8C%E8%AF%81)

> 七、在美国出生，父母双方（或一方）为中国公民且出生时中国籍父母均未取得美国“绿卡”或其他国家
> 永久居留权的申请人须额外提供的材料包括：
>
> （一）出生证或其他具有法律效力亲子关系证明原件。
>
> （二）父母双方有效护照原件。
>
> （三）申请人出生时父母双方在国外居留状况证明（如工作、学习签证、I-94、I-797、I-20表、2019表等或证明父母在申请人出生时不具有任何其他国家国籍、未获得任何其他国家永久居留权的公证书等）原件；
>
> （四）如委托他人办理，需提供委托公证书及受委托人护照原件。
>
> If the applicant was born in the U.S. to two (or one) Chinese parents
> and neither of the Chinese parents had a "green card" or permanent
> residency of any other country at the time of birth, additional documents must
> be provided, including
>
> (a) Original birth certificate or other legally valid proof of
> parentage.
>
> (2) Original valid passports of both parents.
>
> (c) Original certificates of residence status abroad of both parents
> at the time of birth (such as work or study visas, I-94, I-797,
> I-20, DS-2019, etc. or notarized certificates stating that the
> parents did not have the nationality of any other country at the time
> of birth and had not obtained permanent residency in any other
> country).
>
> (d) If delegated to another person, the original notarized certificate of
> delegation and the passport of the delegated person are required.

However, due to Covid-related reasons, the Los Angeles consulate (jurisdiction over Southern California, NM, AZ, HI, Guam, CNMI, American Samoa) currently do not require originals of the documents. Clear scans or photos of both parents' passports and status documents, in addition to signed consent forms, are however still required.

You could also contact the responsible consulate of your residence area or try asking your attorney to see if the court or the State Department may be able to transmit a message to the responsible Chinese mission, but the cooperation of Chinese or any other foreign authorities is not guaranteed. They may not have a system in place to have a warning note for each case, so even if the consular staff is open to take your concerns seriously, they might forget about your request in a few weeks.

Comment: I believe that since last year, applications for PRC passports and travel documents at PRC consulates in the US are done through an app. Do you know if the requirements you mentioned above still apply?

Comment: @user102008 Yes, if the responsible mission lists them. For example, the Embassy in D.C. mentions the documents be submitted *in addition* to the app confirmation by mail to the embassy. The app only serves as preprocessing and pre-approval tool (unless the consulate decides to waive the original document requirement, e.g. in the L.A. consular district).